# Three JS Projection Issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to look at a polygon's center in 3d space then convert its points to 2d screen coordinates. This is the code that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//calculate the center
var center = new THREE.Vector3();
for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    center.add(positions[i]);
}
center.multiplyScalar(1 / positions.length);
//look at the center
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
camera.lookAt(center);
//calculate the screen coordinates
for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    screenPositions.push(toScreenXY(positions[i], camera, width, height));
}

function toScreenXY(position, camera, width, height) {
    var pos = position.clone();
    pos.project(camera);
    var halfWidth = width / 2,
        halfHeight = height / 2;
    return {
        x: (pos.x + 1) * halfWidth + halfWidth,
        y: (-pos.y + 1) * halfHeight + halfHeight
    };

}
```

It is as though the camera transformations have no effect on the projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you changed the camera's rotation, you need to update the camera's world matrix, because the method `project()` references it.

```
camera.position.set( x, y, z );
camera.lookAt( center );

camera.updateMatrixWorld(); // add this
```

The renderer calls `camera.updateMatrixWorld()` for you in `renderer.render()`, but in this case, you have to call it yourself.

three.js r.71